# How to access component model from outside

Tags: sapui5

I have created a shell-in-shell construct in the *index.html*:

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
     // create a new Shell that contains the root view
     var oShell = new sap.m.Shell({
         id: "appShell",
         app: new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
             name: "internal_app",
             height: "100%"
         })
    });

    // load the view that contains the unified shell
    var oAppShellView = sap.ui.view({
        type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML,
        viewName: "internal_app.view.AppShell"
    });
    // access the unified shell from the view
    var oUnifiedShell = oAppShellView.byId("unifiedShell");
    // place the app shell in the unified shell
    oUnifiedShell.addContent(oShell);
    oAppShellView.placeAt("content");
});
```

In addition, a default model has been defined in manifest.json:

```
....
},
"models": {
  "": {
    "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel"
  }
},
....
```

In the controller of the view `internal_app.view.AppShell` (which has been created by the code snippet above) I would now like to access the default model but neither `this.getModel()` nor `this.getOwnerComponent().getModel()` (`getModel()` and `getOwnerComponent()` return `undefined`) worked. I assume that the AppShell controller does not have an owner. But how can I access the default model in the `onInit` of that controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app structure in your case is somewhat unusual - Nevertheless, you can always access the model, defined in `manifest.json`, as long as you can access the inner component.

Assuming `this` is referencing the controller instance of `internal_app.view.AppShell`, you can get the default model like this:

```js
onInit: async function() { // Element required from "sap/ui/core/Element"
  const mySapMShell = /*...*/;
  const component = await this.componentLoaded(mySapMShell.getApp());
  const myDefaultModel = component.getModel(); // model from manifest.json
  // ...
},

componentLoaded: function(componentContainer) {
  const component = componentContainer.getComponent();
  return component ? Promise.resolve(component) : new Promise(resolve => {
    componentContainer.attachEventOnce("componentCreated", event => {
      resolve(event.getParameter("component"));
    });
  });
},
```

Comment: Hi Boghyon, thanks for your code. But I do have a couple of additional questions:

* You said that this setting is some kind of akward. What would you have done instead?
* I understood that the global model is always accessible but it seems that it still need to be bound to the view, correct?
* In the UI5 inspector extension I can see that the values in the model have been correctly changed but the values are not displayed on the AppShell view. I am using the ShellHeadUserItem of the Unified Shell. The username is not updated. Why?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AntonSack About the setting: Shell is supposed to be a _root control_, meaning it should exist only once within the whole document. Thus, having nested Shells can be perceived as an anti-pattern. But I can't say more than this since I don't know anything about your project. Also `sap.unified.Shell` is deprecated.

Comment: @AntonSack The AppShell view is not aware of the changes occurred in the component model since models don't propagate to the parent (AppShell view) but to children only. There are several ways to update parents but that's a whole different topic I'd ask in a separate question.

Comment: Hi Boghyon, I haven't seen a control that replaces the UnifiedShell in the case that there is a toolbar on top while the app views are exchanged in its content being displayed with margins on the left and the right. The tnt.ToolPage only offers full width display.